# Вывод сообщения после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите как вывести сообщение об успешной отправке формы под кнопкой?

```
<form action="#" class="form">
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя*" required />
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="E-Mail" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать E-Mail в формате no-name@mail.com</span>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Телефон" pattern="[\+]\d{1}\s[\(]\d{3}[\)]\s\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2}" minlength="18" maxlength="18" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать телефон в формате +7 (123) 456-78-90</span>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="url" name="name" placeholder="Ваш сайт" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать URL в формате http://mysite.ru</span>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="info container"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите как вывести сообщение об успешной отправке формы под кнопкой?

Вот отправка и проверка:

```js
var f = document.querySelector('form')

f.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(this) // Сборка формы 
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: data // Отправка самой формы
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => { // Ответ
      if (json.id === 101) { // Для примера проверка пройдена если id === 101
        // Добавление поля
        var info = document.querySelector('.info')
        info.innerText = 'Удачно Отправлено'
      }
      // Дебаг узнать что прошла форма
      console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <div class="form__field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя*" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="E-Mail" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать E-Mail в формате no-name@mail.com</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <input type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Телефон" pattern="[\+]\d{1}\s[\(]\d{3}[\)]\s\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2}" minlength="18" maxlength="18" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать телефон в формате +7 (123) 456-78-90</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form__field">
    <input type="url" name="name" placeholder="Ваш сайт" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать URL в формате http://mysite.ru</span>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <div class="info container"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Благодарю за https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd не за что =) его можно еще и локально у себя установить.

Comment: Уже в npm :) ___________

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="info container">Текст</div>` сделать display: none; Если используется AJAX то он возвращает с сервера ответ. В ответе, если success можно задавать этому контейнеру display:block; a с помощью SetTimeout через несколько секунд убирать сообщение, задавая ему снова display:none;

П.С. в этом случае сообщение будет выводиться **не просто по клику, а лишь если форма реально отправлена** и с сервера пришел ответ. А если хотите чтоб в любом случае была надпись - вешайте событие на клик.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="#" class="form"
  onsubmit="document.querySelector('.info.container').textContent = 'Успешно отправлено.';" 
  target="formFrame">
  <iframe name="formFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<div class="form__field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя*"  />
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="email" name="name" placeholder="E-Mail" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать E-Mail в формате no-name@mail.com</span>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="tel" name="name" placeholder="Телефон"  maxlength="18" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать телефон в формате +7 (123) 456-78-90</span>
</div>
<div class="form__field">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваш сайт" />
    <span class="form__error">Это поле должно содержать URL в формате http://mysite.ru</span>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
<div class="info container"></div>
</form>
```